# R, how to visualize PCA

Tags: r

I have faced a wall, I have my data and I want to show PCA. data lookis like this:

```
              mean_HL  mean_LL  mean_FL  mean_ML
 AT1G01080.1  6659961  2481626  3334466  1917721
 AT1G01090.1 14305565 15664978 16938777 13772388
 AT1G01320.1  2417028  7043427 15705767  6236322
 AT1G01790.1  1689920  4840314  6193037  1870497
 AT1G02140.1  5878921  3766975  3536914  3674864
 AT1G02150.1  3271086  2408324  1741409  4520847
 >
```

PCA I am calculating like this

```
tbl_log <- log(MERGE[, 1:4])
Light_mean_PCA <- prcomp(tbl_log,
                       center = TRUE,
                       scale. = TRUE)
```

and next I would like to visualise, and that's where the wall comes in.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ggbiplot", "vqv")

library(ggbiplot)
g <- ggbiplot(Light_mean_PCA, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
          groups = row.names(Light_mean_PCA), ellipse = TRUE, 
          circle = TRUE)
g <- g + scale_color_discrete(name = "")
g <- g + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
           legend.position = 'top')
print(g)
```

or in more simple way

```
library(ggfortify); library(ggplot2)
autoplot(prcomp(tbl_log), data = MERGE, colour = MERGE[,c(1,2,3,4)])
```

I am doing it like this. But I want to have colours depending on: mean_HL,  mean_LL,  mean_FL,  mean_ML from the original table.

How to get 4 different colours for four different light conditions in experiment?

Comment: using your example data you get 6 points plotted. How you want to color them with four conditions? Instead of using ggplot you can also try base R `plot(Light_mean_PCA$x[,1:2])`

Comment: https://filebin.net/ofqu1xw32wu9vy4j  I got a plot like this when i sued the code provided by Jimbou, I want to have it like this but colored by the conditions. SO maybe I provided so small egxample. but it's just a head from my data, so is it possible to annote colours from the original table colnames?